# Dúvida MySQLi Paramento new_link

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

A antiga função de PHP `mysql_connect` possuía o parametro `new_link` que permitia conexão com vários bancos diferentes no mesmo `script`:

Exemplo:

```
$connect = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass,$new_link);
```

Como funciona isso em mysqli? Ele tem esse parâmetro? Ou não precisa?

```
$mysqli = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $database);
```

Pesquisei na documentação mas não localizei.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cada instância `mysqli` é completamente independentes uma da outra e, portanto, cada conexão db de uma instância é um `new_link`. Portanto, não existe nada equivalente ao `new_link` no `mysqli`.

Answer (score 0):

O quarto argumento da função `mysql_connect()` serve para obrigar o php a criar uma nova conexão, o comportamento padrão é uma chamado `mysql_connect()` ele retorna a conexão, no caso de uma segunda com as mesmas informações(servidor, usuário senha) ele retorna a mesma conexão, na extensão do mysqli não exite esse parametro.